# Selecting first item in listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

A listbox works as an auto-complete within a richtextbox I am populating it with items from a collection. I need it to auto select first item every time listbox populates.

How do I do this?

Thank you

```
foreach (var ks in ksd.FindValues(comparable))
      {
          lb.Items.Add(ks.Value);
      }

      if (lb.HasItems)
      {
          lb.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
          lb.SelectedIndex = 0; //Suggested solution, still doesn't work 
      }
      else
      {
          lb.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
      }
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can put **SelectedIndex** to **0** in XAML for the first time loading

```
<ListBox SelectedIndex="0" />
```

In code-behind, you can do this after loading items list

```
        if (this.lst.Items.Count > 0)
            this.lst.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: this is what I have and its not working <ListBox Height="67" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="lb" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="49" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="12,32,0,0" ListBoxItem.Selected="lbSelected" SelectedIndex="0" />

Comment: How to you populate your list? I mean do you use binding?

Comment: No. I am populating it with listbox.Items.Add() Thanks for help

Comment: The first selection item have index 0. So you can do like my post. (after editing)

Comment: Still not working something might be wrong with my code. I'll go through and post it if I don't figure it out. Thanks

Comment: For a ListView this would only select the first item. If you want focus as well then you might have to do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11747701/1201038).

Answer (score 14):

If you're using MVVM then you can also try another solution:

1. Add property called `SelectedValue` to the ViewModel;
2. After loading (or adding) values to the `List` that you bind to the `ListBox` set `SelectedValue` with`valuesList.FirstOrDefault();`
3. On the XAML bind the `SelectedItem` property of the `ListBox` to `SelectedValue`
   (from ViewModel) and set binding `Mode="TwoWay"`

Comment: I know it's been a couple years, but it definitely should be the accepted answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
listBox1.SetSelected(0,true);
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need anything just the data you use. You shouldn't be interested how the Control looks like.
(You don't want to be coupled with that control)

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding MyItem}" />
```

could be:

```
<SexyWoman Legs="{Binding MyItems}" Ass="{Binding MyItem}" />
```

and it will work as well.

The ListBox has this class as a DataContext:

```
class DummyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private MyItem _myItem;
    public MyItem MyItem
    {
        get { return _myItem; }
        set { _myItem = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("MyItem"); }
    }

    private IEnumerable<MyItem> _myItems;
    public IEnumerable<MyItem> MyItems
    {
        get { return _myItems; }        
    }

    public void FillWithItems()
    {
        /* Some logic */
        _myItems = ...

        NotifyPropertyChanged("MyItems");

        /* This automatically selects the first element */
        MyItem = _myItems.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string value)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(value));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: -1: Sorry, I totally don't understand how any of your examples actually answer the question on hand. I think it would be helpful if you could just put in the specific code block, rather than the entire VM?