# Set Item Focus in ListView WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, focus, wpf-controls

is there any way to accomplish this functionality from WinForms in WPF?

```
ListView.FocusedItem = ListView.Items[itemToFocusIndex]
```

I'm trying to manually set **focus** (not select) on item in WPF ListView. From *System.Windows.Controls*.
Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are two types of focus in WPF - Keyboard Focus and Logical Focus. [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768.aspx) can give you more information about focus in WPF.

You can either do this:

```
ListViewItem item = myListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as ListViewItem;
item.Focus();
```

It's also possible to call

```
Keyboard.Focus(item);
```

If you also want to scroll the `ListView` to the item's position, add this:

```
myListView.ScrollIntoView(item);
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** For this to work, you will need to set `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"` on your `ListView`, which may cause it to perform slower. The reason this attached property is required is that when the `ListView` is virtualized (which it is by default), the `ListViewItems` aren't created for items that aren't displayed on the screen, which will cause `ContainerFromIndex()` to return `null`.

Comment: Well I got the idea behind your code, but it's not working as _myListView.Items[itemIndex] as IInputElement;_ returns _null_.
The items in the ListView are instances of my custom class and the proper style is selected at runtime according to instace property. The class does not inherit of implement any class or interface respectively; so I cannot cast it to IInputElement...

Comment: @jnovacho Any control inheriting from `UIElement` implements `IInputElement`. What type of object do you get from `myListView.Items[itemIndex]`?

Comment: I get only Object from that Collection.

Comment: @jnovacho Look in the debugger and see what's the actual type that's being held there.

Comment: So in the collection are actually stored instances of my custom class. Which only has two properties. Flag for choosing appropriate style, using DataTemplateSelector and second property which holds the actual data displayed in the UI.

Comment: Very important to check if the ListViewItem is null and call `ListView.UpdateLayout()`. Then calling the `...ContainerFromIndex` won't be null.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use Keyboard.FocusedElement to get the focused element in the listview.

```
Keyboard.FocusedElement
```

should return the focused element

Comment: I don't need getting the focused item, I need to **set** the focus.

Answer (score 0):

ListView items are UIElements, so simply use `UIElement.Focus()`. e.g., `listViewItem.Focus()` or `button.Focus()` and so on.

Answer (score -2):

```
    public void foucusItem( ListView.Item itemToFocusIndex){
         int count = 0; 
         foreach(ListView.Item item in YourListView){
               if(item == itemsToFocusIndex){
                     ListView.Items[count].Focus();
                     return;
               }
         count++;
         }
    }
```

Comment: There is no Focus() method. I'm using WPF not Forms!

Comment: Make sure that its Focusable property is set to true.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview.aspx
I think  there is a Focus() method. look at the link about half way down under methods.

Comment: The Focus is there for whole ListView, not for individual items.

Answer (score -2):

```
//to set focus write
CollistView7.Items[TheIndItem].Selected = true; 
CollistView7.Select();
CollistView7.Items[TheIndItem].Focused = true;
//when TheIndItem is the index
```