# How to focus on the current ListView item that just add

Tags: wpf, listview

i have `WPF` application and `ListView`.
When add files into the `ListView` i can see only the first 10 items and when adding another files i can see only the `Vertical Scroll Bar` and i want when add files that the focus will be on the last item that added.
So i try to Select the last item:

```
listview.SelectedIndex = lvPcapFiles.Items.Count - 1;
```

or

```
listview.SelectedItem = lvPcapFiles.Items.Count - 1;
```

But the first option only select the last item but the focus is still no there.

The second do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
 listview.SelectedIndex = lvPcapFiles.Items.Count - 1;
 listview.ScrollIntoView(listview.SelectedItem);
```

There are some articles for you. 
 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745028/set-item-focus-in-listview-wpf)