# How to change the focused item in a ListView during a DragDrop event?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a ListView with DragDrop function. I want the dragged item to keep selected after the DragDrop.

I have this code (for the DragDrop)

```
private void commandListView_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Point point = commandListView.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    int index = 0;

    try
    {
        index = commandListView.GetItemAt(point.X, point.Y).Index;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }

    if (index < 0)
    {
        index = commandListView.Items.Count - 1;
    }

    ListViewItem data = e.Data.GetData(typeof(ListViewItem)) as ListViewItem;
    commandListView.Items.Remove(data);
    commandListView.Items.Insert(index, data);
}
```

And i tried to use this this to select the item again but it doesnt work

```
data.Selected = true;
data.Focused = true;
```

Then i tested to see if i could focus on the first item in the ListView

```
commandListView.Items[0].Selected = true;
commandListView.Items[0].Focused = true;
```

but it didnt work either, the selected item doesnt change. its always the old index where the dragged item was before the dragdrop.

PS. I'm using WinForms

**@Update**

I already tried to use

```
commandListView.Focus();
```

but it didnt worked

Just to clarify the dragdrop is happening inside the same ListView, i'm dragging items to change their order.

Comment: Side note: `catch (Exception) {}` (ignoring all the exceptions thrown) should never ever be used

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745028/set-item-focus-in-listview-wpf

Comment: `commandListView.Focus();` You have to focus the control itself after focus item.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko yeah, i know, i'm using this as a personal tool the last thing i want are exceptions hahahahah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution; i was using the MouseDown event to start the DragDrop operation.

Now i use the ItemDrag event and everything works fine, actually i dont even need to focus the item, it's done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

For those still trying to find a solution:

```
int counter = ...; // your code to find index of wanted ListView-Item.

ListVieuwName.Focus(); //First: activate focus on the entire ListView.

ListVieuwName.Items[counter].Selected = true; //Next: select your wanted ListView-Item.
```

This should do it...