# Scroll to last added item in listview when using binding

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding

I want to add an item to listview then select and scroll to it. but scroll  doesn't move to the item. when I try to add many item, scroll moves to an item but it is not the last added one. It seems listviewItem doesn't generate immediately after adding item using binding.

I tried to add an item then select it (using binding) and scroll to last selected item. But it do not work because count of selected items will be zero.

```
if (lV.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
// do it here (but it will not run because lV.SelectedItems.Count is zero)
}
```

I also tried to get item from binding but returned value will be null.

```
ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)lV.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(lastItem);
//but item will be null
```

Note that I also used `VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"` as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11747701/11178547).

As select by binding works well I considered binding focus but `IsFocused` property only lets get not set. So how can I do it?

=========================================================

Edit: I have following codes in xaml:

```
    <local:PrefectListView x:Name="lV" 
                                          AllowDrop="true"
                                          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 

   VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"
                                          SelectionChanged="lVImage_SelectionChanged"
                                          PreviewKeyDown="lV_PreviewKeyDown"
                                          Drop="lV_Drop"
                                          DragEnter="lV_DragEnter" 
                                          ItemDragsAndDropedToPC="lV_ItemDragsAndDropedToPC" >

                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Grid  Width="80" Height="120" >
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding Thumbnail}" Margin="5"/>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5,0,5,5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                                       TextWrapping="Wrap"  TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>

                                    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </ListView.ItemsPanel>

                                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="lVItem_MouseDoubleClick"/>
                                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,2,2"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

                            </local:PrefectListView>
```

In cs, after creating item I add it to `_navigationSources` and then use following code to select and scroll to it:

```
private void SelectItems(bool clearPreviousSelecteds, bool focus, NavigationPanItemRow[] rows)
        {
            //force to run it on UI thread
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                //check arguments
                if (rows == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("rows"); }
                //
                for (int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (rows[i] == null)
                    { throw new ArgumentException("Atleast one of members is null", "rows"); }
                }

                //variables
                NavigationPanItemRow lastItem = null;

                //clear all selected
                if (clearPreviousSelecteds)
                {
                    _navigationSources.UnSelectAll();
                }

                //select
                for (int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++)
                {
                    rows[i].IsSelected = true;
                    lastItem = rows[i];
                }

                //focus (I use it ) 
                if (focus && lastItem != null)
                {
                    lV.Focus();
                    ListViewItem it = (ListViewItem)lV.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(lastItem);
                    lV.ScrollIntoView(it);
                }

                //focus (also it)
                if (focus && lV.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    lV.Focus();
                    ((ListViewItem)lV.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(lV.SelectedItems[lV.SelectedItems.Count - 1])).Focus();
                }
            }));
        }
```

Note: if I add a messagebox before focus part, As it will provide some time, code works well.

Comment: Hi NewComer, welcome to Stackoverflow! It is not clear how you hooked up the event handlers in your code. In order for us to help you, please provide all the relevant c# and xaml code in your question.

Comment: @Tobias Hoefer, thanks for your comment. I provided some codes.

Comment: At last I used a timer and selected items in tick event. it is not prefect but it works.